# Drupal Commerce - Retrieve cart value

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to create a popup notification on a route that shows the current cart value (subtotal) and notifies users to add $X.XX to receive free shipping.

I have extended a route to add new functionality but I'm unsure whether a hook or service would be best/appropriate.  I can't seem to find any documentation on cart value--I can see some functions for retrieving quantity of items and seemingly could calculate the price by retrieving the prices for each individual item but research isn't bringing up much.

I see information regarding **Order Totals** but one would seemingly have to finish the order process in order to retrieve that data.  I'm trying to grab cart value when a user goes to the `/cart` page.

I'm not asking for anything specific, just a pointer in the right direction.  Thank you.

Comment: you can grab cart quantity & value in a view, display the view in your popup, i sugest you to clone the cart view, disable the original one, then modify the cloned one.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, I will look into that--did not think to start with that.  Thank you!! Edit:  nevermind I'm pretty sure you can render a view from code so I don't think that should be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the store id and order type then

```
$store_id = 1;
$order_type = 'default';
$cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
$cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityManager();
$store = $entity_manager->getStorage('commerce_store')->load($store_id); 
$cart = $cart_provider->getCart($order_type, $store);
$cart->get('total_price')->getValue()[0]['number'];
```

Comment: Why is it important to know the store id?  Orders aren't separated by store ID so it seems pointless to require that information...

Comment: Every cart/order has a store ID @cchoe1, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255431/how-to-load-current-user-cart-in-commerce-2